# How to replace instance attributes/getters when switching from class components to functional components?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I am in the process to convert some old class based react components to functional components.

Lets say I have following `Dashboard` component, consisting of `Input` and `Chart`:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Calculation from './calculation';
    export default function Dashboard(properties){
    
      const [data, setData] = React.useState();
      const input = renderInput(setData);
      const chart = renderChart(data);
    
      React.useEffect(async ()=> {
         //initialize chart data if input is valid
         if(input.isValid){
            const inputData = input.data;
            const result = await Calculation.calculate(inputData);
            setData(data);        
         }
      })
    
      return <>
        {input}
        {chart}
      </>
    }
   ...
   function renderInput(setData){
      const dataChanged = async inputData => {
          const result = await Calculation.calculate(inputData);
          setData(result);                
      }
      ...
   }
   function renderChart(data){
      ...
   }
```

If `Input` is a class based component, I can define accessible attributes `isValid`, `data` for it, e.g.

```
get isValid(){
   return this._validata(this.data);
}
```

Those attributes can be accessed during the initialization step, that is currently defined in the scope of the Dashboard.

**Is this still possible, if  Input is converted to a functional react component?**

a) If so, how can I define and use the attributes "isValid", "data" for the functional component?

b) If not, how should I restructure the above code?

Should I move the initialization and calculation from the Dashboard down into the Input component? Then the `Input` would know about the Calculation and I would like to avoid that.